# Consider Paypal fees in accounting

Tags: united-states, income-tax, fees, accounting, paypal

I'm a freelancer. I sent an invoice to my client (using InvoiceBubble.com), which he decided to pay via Paypal. Paypal took a fee.

How do I take this fee in consideration for my accounting? I marked the invoice as paid for $877.83 but really I received $852.07. How does this work with accounting and taxes?

Now that's not a big difference, but it can add up with several clients, some with much larger amounts.

Answer (score 8):

The exact heads under which you classify this would vary from country to county. Essentially you would need to treat as;
- The fee charged by Paypal as Expense under some head.
- The taxes would be on profit, so apart from your cost, the fee would also get deducted as expense and tax would be on the profit after this.

Comment: Treated the same as any bank charge on an account transaction...

Answer (score 4):

You should classify this as an expense in an account called **Bank Service Charge.**

Comment: But is there like a "receipt" from paypal to show that I paid fees?

Comment: @nute The paypal page shows the fee they took.